# c++ - Returning "false" in an int returning function

Tags: c++, null, return

I have an int function that searches an array for a value, and if the value is found it returns the value of the position in the array. If the value isn't found, I simply put 
`return false;`
Would that give me the same result as `return 0;`? 
I would also like to know what exactly would happen if I did `return NULL;`.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike PHP and other languages, C++ types aren't changed on the fly.
A way to do what you want (return false if something didn't work but return an int if it did) would be to define the function with a return type of bool but also pass an int reference (int&) in it. You return true or false and assign the reference to the correct value. Then, in the caller, you see if true was returned and then use the value.

```
bool DoSomething(int input, int& output)
{
    //Calculations here
    if(/*successful*/)
    {
        output = value;
        return true;
    }

    output = 0; //any value really
    return false;
}

// elsewhere
int x = 5;
int result = 0;

if(DoSomething(x, result))
{
    std::cout << "The value is " << result << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Something went wrong" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`false` will be converted to `0` from the draft C++ standard section `4.7` *Integral conversions* paragraph *4* which says (*emphasis mine going foward*):

> [...]If the source type is bool, **the value false is converted to zero** and
>   the value true is converted to one.

I think most people would find that odd but it is valid. As for `NULL` section `4.10` *Pointer conversions* says:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) prvalue of integer type **that evaluates to zero** or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t. [...]

Comment: That's what I had suspected, I was just hoping it would work like a boolean because I used the actual word false. I'll just use a different method. Thank you. NULL would just go to 0 also? Well then. Thank you for the very complete answer.

Comment: @ChrisVachon well `0` will convert to `false` and non-zero to `true`, not totally sure what you are trying to do though.

Comment: I'm actually trying to go the other way around. I'm supposed to return an int but return the value false.

Comment: is it actually possible to return a data type that is different from return type declared in function prototype in c++ ? it is possible in c (in turboC at least)

Comment: Using false or NULL will return 0 ... HOWEVER there is no way to tell either of those translated zeros from an actual zero result.  if zero is a valid legitimate return value, then you may be getting a false sense of security from using keywords NULL or false.